# bundle exec rake db:populate >> rake aborted - Validation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rake, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm currently going through the RoR guides, and i'm stuck at...

"Adding following/follower relationships to the sample data."

Here's the code that is suppose to work: `sample_app/lib/task/sample_data.rake`

```
namespace :db do
desc "Fill database with sample data"
task populate: :environment do
    make_users
    make_microposts
    make_relationships
  end
end

def make_users
 admin = User.create!(name:     "Example User2",
                     email:    "example2@railstutorial.org",
                     password: "foobar",
                     password_confirmation: "foobar")
admin.toggle!(:admin)
99.times do |n|
 name  = Faker::Name.name
 email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
 password  = "password"
 User.create!(name:     name,
              email:    email,
              password: password,
              password_confirmation: password)
  end
end

def make_microposts
  users = User.all(limit: 6)
  50.times do
    content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
    users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }
  end
end

def make_relationships
  users = User.all
  user  = users.first
  followed_users = users[2..50]
  followers      = users[3..40]
  followed_users.each { |followed| user.follow!(followed) }
  followers.each      { |follower| follower.follow!(user) }
end
```

when i do `rake db:reset` my database reset with no problems.

when i do `rake db:populate` an error occurred stating this:

```
 rake aborted!
 Validation failed: Follower can't be blank`
```

so i checked my database, and all tables were populated except for "relationships" table.. any thoughts or suggestions? I'm pretty sure there's a problem with the code, `def making_relationships`, to be exact. hope anyone has a solution to this..

-Marc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're calling `.create!` on models like `User` and `Micropost` (`user.microposts`), it is one of them throwing the error mentioned.

Please, post the code for these models to enable us answer more specifically.

You can still debug the problem by yourself though. Just hit `rails c` in the projects root directory, and try to create instances with the very same attributes you're trying in rake task:

```
$ rails c

$ user = User.create!(name:     name,
                      email:    email,
                      password: password,
                      password_confirmation: password)

$ micropost = user.microposts.create!(content: "Hello, cruel world!")

# by this step you should already see some errors raised; if that's not sufficient,
# call the following methods to figure out what model suffers the validation error
user.errors.full_messages
micropost.errors.full_messages
```

Anyway, it's the validation that's not satisfied. Double check you're passing all required attributes passed when creating a model with a shebang `create!`. Specifically check which model requires presence of `Follower` (whatever that is).

Comment: i tried the console it displays that no errors where found. " [] " was shown in both error finding methods. as for the follower code, it lies in the relationship model and user model. here's a link for the gist of the entire code: https://gist.github.com/2768605

Comment: @Marc, try running "rake db:populate --trace" to determine what exact line throws the error.

Comment: From the `User` model code I'm looking at it seems that creating followers doens't work well. As stated previously, try invoking console and running something like `user = User.first; user.follow!(User.last)`

Comment: i tried your task @gmile with using your code for the console. it shows the same error i receive in my git. here's the output of it.. https://gist.github.com/2774192 -- i tried looking into some of the files manually by going through the files but it's out of my knowledge and comprehension on how to solve this validation problem.. or whatever problem this may be

Comment: Right now it's the `Validation failed: Email has already been taken`. It seems that you're trying to create a user which already exists, which is possible if you ran the script multiple times already without dropping the users table

Comment: yeah i understand.. i dropped it twice already and the first time i try to populate it, validation fails due to "follower can't be blank" the second time i try to populate it it states that validation fails due to "email duplication" i didn't drop it just now, so let me just do that real quick and redo my gist. sorry about that.

Comment: Marc, looking at the gist (https://gist.github.com/2768605) I just noticed a typo in `models/user.rb` line 8. The value under `foreign_key:` key is `followed id` while it should be `followed_id`. Not sure if that'll help though

Comment: unfortunately the minor typo hasn't changed a thing :( i even spotted `Relationships`  as my classname: which should actually be `Relationship` but even with that update it still doesn't want to show the green light. here's the the output of my git after doing `rake db:populate --trace` .. https://gist.github.com/2774192

Comment: actually i spotted a problem in my `model/relationship.rb` file.. hoping this will solve the problem. line 2, it was never stated to add :follower_id as part of `attr_accessible` ... i'm crossing my fingers on this one

Comment: Try in console the following:
`x = User.create(some_valid_user_attrs)`
`rel = x.relationships.new(followed_id: 10)`
`rel.inspect`

now does rel object have both `:followed_id`, `:follower_id` set up?

Comment: irb(main):012:0> rel.inspect
=> "#<Relationship id: nil, follower_id: nil, followed_id: 101, created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>"

Comment: See 6th line in `models/user.rb`. Try changing `followed_id` to `follower_id`

Comment: oooooo em geee.. i can't believe i missed that @_@ it works! 1000 thanks to you :)